# How to multiply each row of the softmax by a specific matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

The problem I am trying to solve is the following: 
given the output of my softmax, `y_pred`, with dimension `[batch_size, n_classes]`, and a tensor containing one matrix for every prediction, `T`, that means that the tensor has dimension `[batch_size, n_classes, n_classes]`.

I want to be able to multiply every row of `y_pred` by one of the matrix from `T` and save the result in `y_pred` in every iteration training step.

Example:

```
y_pred[0,:] = y_pred[0,:]*T[0,;,:]
y_pred[1,:] = y_pred[1,:]*T[1,;,:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code sample should give you the result that you want.

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size=3
num_classes=7
y_pred = tf.random_normal((batch_size, num_classes))
T = tf.random_normal((batch_size, num_classes, num_classes))

output = []
for i in range(batch_size):
  output.append(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(y_pred[i], axis=0), T[i]))

y_pred = tf.concat(output, axis=0)
```